# django ORM: get all the fields of model with positive value in one field

Tags: python, django

I am trying to query all the objects in a model that have a positive value in one particular field.

I have not been able to find anywhere whether there is a way to use `greater than` signs in django. I have tried doing by sorting the column that interests me and removing the 0 values in that column in order to the overcome the greater than. First it seems over complicated, and second it does not work.

here is the query:

```
count_orders = replenishment.objects.order_by(F('StockOnOrder')).desc().exclude('StockOnOrder' = 0)
```

I also need to count the positive rows in this field and it does not work either as following:

```
count_orders = replenishment.objects.order_by(F('StockOnOrder')).desc().exclude('StockOnOrder' = 0).count()
```

both give me the error:

```
keyword can't be an expression
```

I am wondering if by chance this is the proper way to do it, or if there is something more intuitive and simple.

Comment: Have yout tried `gt`? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#gt

Comment: I guess i need to read the doc more carefully...this did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use gt.

```
model.objects.filter(your_field__gt=0)
```